# Send ETW events to Application Insights?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights, etw

I have some legacy code hosted in an Azure WebJob (.exe) that is generating a lot of ETW events for logging to a custom Event Provider.

How can I get those ETW events to Application Insights in an easy way? I would like them to show up in the same AI instance as my Website that is hosting the WebJob.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of Event source tracking module.
https://github.com/AlexBulankou/ai-samples/blob/master/ETWTrackingModule.cs

The module wraps ETW listener that subscribes for configured event sources. You can specify what event sources you would like to subscribe to and whether you would like your ETW events to be tracked events and/or as traces. In your ApplicationInsights.config, register this module as follows:

```
 <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Samples.ETWTrackingModule, YourAssemblyName">
  <TrackEvent>True</TrackEvent>
  <TrackTrace>True</TrackTrace>
  <EventSources>
    <Add Name="System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentCollectionsEventSource" EventLevel="LogAlways"/>
    <Add Name="System.Diagnostics.Eventing.FrameworkEventSource" EventLevel="LogAlways"/>
  </EventSources>
</Add>
```

Comment: How can I add the ApplicationInsights.config and the NuGets to my WebJob? It is just an .exe in my WebJob, I don't have access to modifying the code. Also, how can I specify the ETW provider I want logged to Application Insights?

Comment: I was assuming with my answer that you can enable Application Insights by installing Nuget packages and redeploy your console application as Azure web job. Is this not that case?

Comment: As I cant modify the original code for the exe I cant really see how to get this working. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I understand you can not modify code and redeploy, but can you drop additional files (binaries and AppInsights.config) into your web job folder using Kudu console?